# In WordPress, should it be possible change a word in all pages of a site in once time?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I know it sounds crazy, but as asked above, i have lots of pages with the word "Vocal" between  and  tags and i would like to change this word to "Voices". Make it one page by one would be very tiring and take a lot of time. If it is not possible, "Vocal" should remain as it is. Thanks for any help!

Comment: This guy writes excellent plugins, Search&Replace is one of them: https://profiles.wordpress.org/bueltge#content-plugins

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to export your WordPress database to a `.sql` file.

(possibly you would only need to export your `wp_posts` table, if you only really need to replace it in the page/post content and nowhere else in your entire site)

Then open it in a text editor of your choosing and do a find replace.

Search for `%Vocal%`

Notice the the `%` symbol, just replace them with a blank space.

Then do a replace with `%Voices%`.

After you are done save the `.sql` file and import it to your database.

Of course keep an original backup of the file, in case anything goes wrong :)

Comment: Hey, good to know there are solutions. I opted for a newer plugin (Search & Replace), which allows you to backup the database. So I succeeded precisely in replacing the word. It worked very well. Thank you all very much for your attention.

Comment: Very cool, didn't know there was a plugin for it, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

**First backup your database!** Then run the SQL command

```
update wp_posts set post_content = replace( post_content, 'Vocal', 'Voices' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/ It hasn't been updated in a while, but it works. You can find/replace with either grep or plain text in post content, post meta, etc. No reason to use PHPMyAdmin or run database queries. Backup your database first.